# Integrated modified OLS estimation for cointegration

Tags: r, least-squares, panel-data, cointegration, endogeneity

I am testing whether the variable Xj is a part of the single equation cointegrating relation of Y with X1, X2, ..., Xn using `cointReg` R package. The variables Y and X's are time series variables. The `cointReg` package is based on the paper entitled "Integrated modified (IM) OLS estimation and fixed-inference for cointegrating regressions" by Timothy J.Vogelsanga and Martin Wagner. The variables can be endogenous.

I would like to know whether I could use some model selection criterion such as AIC to decide between models, for e.g. the model for Y with X1, X2, and X3 as regressors is a better model than the model for Y with X1 and X2 variables. Do the IM-OLS residuals be white noise for the IM-OLS model estimates to be statistically valid or they only require to be stationary? Moreover, can some of the X variables be stationary while others to be integrated of order 1 (I (1))? Lastly, can I use the dummy variable approach (to control for country and time effects) for using this (IM-OLS) model in panel data? If yes, what tests I can perform for model's validity?